# How do I properly update my object variable inside my object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, variables

Every time this program loops, it resets the cash variable back to 500. How do I initially set it to 500, subtract the bet and then have it remember that value on its next iteration? My output for example:

```
Computer 1 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //
Computer 2 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //these are right
Computer 3 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //

Computer 1 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //
Computer 2 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //now should have $400
Computer 3 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //

Computer 1 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //
Computer 2 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //now should have $350
Computer 3 bets: $50 I now have: $450 //
```

My code:

```
public class Computer {
    private int id;
    private int bet;
    private int cash = 500;
    private static Computer[] c;

    public static void create(int numComps) {
        c = new Computer[numComps];

        for (int i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {
            c[i] = new Computer();
            c[i].id = i + 1;
            c[i].bet = 50;
            c[i].cash -= c[i].bet;
            c[i].display();

        }
    }

    private void display() {
        String name = "Computer " + id;
        System.out.println(name + " bets: $" + bet + " I now have: $" + cash);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            create(3);
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        } while (i < 3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you are calling `create`, but logically, `create` should only be called once, as it creates new computer objects. Also, `create` does not do what it says. Not only does it create computer objects, it also makes them bet money, and displays them. `bet` should be a separate method and `create` should not call `display` at all:

```
public static void create(int numComps) {
    c = new Computer[numComps];

    for (int i = 0; i < numComps; i++) {
        c[i] = new Computer();
        c[i].id = i + 1;
        c[i].bet = 50;

    }
}

public void bet() {
    cash -= bet;
}
```

In the `main` method, you should call `bet` and `display`, but only call `create` *once*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    create(3);
    int i = 0;
    do {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++) {
            c[j].bet();
            c[j].display();
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    } while (i < 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Your call to `create(3);` instantiates three new computers every time it is called.

You need to start following the **separation of concerns** rule of software design. Each method in your code should have one job. The `create` method is taking on too many responsibilities.

Your biggest problem here is that static method you have conjured up. It is making this more complicated than it needs to be.

> How do I initially set [the cash variable] to 500

You need to initialize that private field in the constructor.

> subtract the bet

You need to add a public method to a class to allow other code to make changes to its private fields.

> and then have it remember that value on it's next iteration?

You have already taken care of this. As you wrote it, the `Computer` class "remembers" the value of the private field `cash` just fine. The problem is that you are just accidentally instantiating three new `Computer`s on every iteration of your while-loop.